# Solve the logarithmic equation

Tags: summation, logarithms

I have logarithmic problem:
$$\frac{\log \:_{10}\left(1\:+\:\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...\right)}{\log _{10}\left(2+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{9}+...\right)}\cdot \left(\log _2\left(3\right)+\log _3\left(4\right)+\log _{16}\left(3\right)+...+\log _{2^{2n}}\left(3\right)+..\right)$$

I solved first part:
$$\frac{\log \:_{10}\left(2\right)}{\log _{10}\left(3\right)}\cdot \left(\log _2\left(3\right)+\log _3\left(4\right)+\log _{16}\left(3\right)+...+\log _{2^{2n}}\left(3\right)+..\right)$$

But can't understand second part.

Answers:
$A=2, B=-1, C=-2, D=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Did you mean $\log_4 (3)$ in the second part?

Comment: @jiaminglimjm no i didn't mean that

Comment: Don't understand what?  And how can $\log_3(4)$ be "correct"?  Correct about what?  Why is that any more correct than any other mathematical expression?  Anyway what's your question?

Comment: Well, OP seems to mean that the second term in the expression is not a mistake, even though neither first or second seem to fit the remaining term pattern...

Comment: "no i didn't mean that"  Are you sure you don't mean that?  Where did you get this problem from.  Do you have any reason to think it wasn't a typo.  It doesn't make any sense that it's not a typo.

Comment: @fleablood I'm sure

Comment: @fleablood:  the first term wouldn't fit the pattern of taking the log to $2^{2n}$ either.  It doesn't matter to the result.

Comment: Where does this "logarithmic expression" come from?

Answer (score 2):

$$
S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \log_{2^{2n}}(3)
  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \log_{4^n}(3)
  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln 3}{\ln 4^n}
  = \frac{\ln 3}{\ln 4} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}
$$
which diverges.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part we can write for terms after the first two $$\log_{2^{2n}}3=a_n\\
\left(2^{2n}\right)^{a_n}=3\\2^{2na_n}=3\\2^{a_n}=3^{\frac 1{2n}}\\
a_n=\frac 1{2n}\log_23$$
and all the terms after the first two become a diverging harmonic series.

Now that you have added the choices, it is clear the text expects the series to converge.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20(log(2%5E(2n),3)%20)from%202%20to%20infinity) agrees with me-you can see the screenshot below.  I assume the book answer is A.  All the terms are positive, so the result cannot be negative.  The first two terms of the second part are greater than $1$, so the whole expression is greater than $2\frac {\log_{10}2}{\log_{10}3}\approx 1.26$ which rules out D.  Even if it did converge, the irregularity of the first two terms would make me sure the result is not some nice number like $2$.
[image]

Comment: Thanx i appreciate it